# Possible values of %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm writing a batch script for windows 7 and want to handle both 64 bit and and x86 processors.

What are the possible values of the Windows `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` environment variable?

Comment: 'migrated from stackoverflow' ... it's as if someone doesn't think that batch scripting is _proper_ programming!?

Comment: The top answer is outdated as of May 2019. Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1441469/432540) one instead

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx

- AMD64
- IA64
- x86

Note that this doesn't tell you the architecture of the processor but only of the process with the environment variable. It returns "x86" for a 32 bit process running on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: There's a workaround for the "32bit process on 64bit Windows" problem: just check `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432` as well, and if it isn't undefined (i.e. equals to `AMD64` or `IA64`), then this is a 64bit machine. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx).

Comment: Should add `ARM` in there now.

Comment: This answer is outdated as of May 2019. Please see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1441469/432540) one instead.

Answer (score 26):

The top answer is currently outdated. As of May 2019, here are all the valid values of `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`:

*64-bit*:

- `AMD64`
- `IA64`
- `ARM64`
- `EM64T`

(`EM64T` is very rarely seen, almost always on Windows XP-64. You can safely ignore this in your scripts in most cases unless your code needs to be *super* backwards-compatible.)

*32-bit*:

- `X86`

([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details))

Comment: It should be noted that elsewhere it was said that the values should be downcased. I do not know whether it makes a difference, but in other examples I saw "amd64" rather than the all-upcased variant.

Comment: @shevy I don't think it matters, but fwiw, the output of `echo %processor_architecture%` is in all uppercase for me.

Comment: What about 32-bit ARM? I thought that was supported in Windows RT (circa Windows 8).

Answer (score 6):

"EM64T" is also a possible value, however unlikely.
My understanding is that you will only see this with XP-64.