# Will PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE Environment Variable Identify as 32 Bit on a 64 Bit Machine with a 32 Bit OS Installed?

Tags: windows, command-line, 64-bit, 32-bit, environment-variables

If I had a 32 bit version of Windows installed on a 64 bit capable machine, will the following command return "x86"?

```
  echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible values of %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%](http://superuser.com/questions/305901/possible-values-of-processor-architecture)

Comment: I don't agree that it is a duplicatted question, it is asking about a specific situation of returning value.

Comment: @DiogoRocha True, but the accepted answer for that question also answers this question. Specifically, that the value of `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` depends on the bitness of the application calling it. Therefore, unless the OP is using a 32 bit version of cmd.exe, under x64 Windows `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` will return AMD64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this specific situation(32 system over a 64 capable processor), it will return the value of the installed architecture of your Windows, so it will be **x86**.

I've just tested it on my machine([that is 64 capable](http://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-%288M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29)):

Windows buttom + Break returned 32 bits installed system(my system is on portuguese):

[image]

And the echo %processor_architecture% command returned me x86:

[image]

Comment: This holds true for cmd.exe since it's a native x64 application under x64 Windows. Apps running under WoW64 would get a different result (x86.)

Comment: Have you verified this...I don't have a machine to test it on, otherwise I'd check myself.

Comment: Amazed but %Processor_architecture% have nothing to do with the application that is running, but the Windows enviroment variable. It is defined on boot and will stay until someone change it... I mean, it is not controled or will be changed by different applications over the time...

Comment: I'm nowhere near an x64 Windows machine at the moment, so I haven't verified this personally yet. However, this [Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx) states that the WoW64 subsystem always sets `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` to `x86`.

Comment: @DiogoRocha The WoW64 system lies about a whole lot of things to 32 bit apps running under it, including otherwise invariant variables.

Comment: Its a kind of odd situation for me... I mean, if you have two applications running on a 64 bits system, one on 64 bits and another one on Wow64 emulating 32 bits, it is only one variable called %processor_architecture%, how this would works?

Comment: I will change my answear to adept to your comment and answear the specific thread discussion here(variable under 32 system on a 64 bits processor). Thanks for your observations.

Comment: The values of environment variables are stored in the Registry. 32 bit applications under x64 Windows have their registry accesses redirected at the API level. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx