# Batch File Check Directory exists in x64 and/or x86

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I need to be able to run this batch fine on both x86 and x64 machines to check if a program has been installed correctly .

We have an app that installs in x86 in the standard program files directory, and when installed in x64 it installs in the x86 program files directory.

Currently it reports `false`, displays the echo that the app is installed and the echo that the app is not installed when run on x86 and x64.

```
if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="x86" GOTO X86DC
if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="X64" GOTO X64DC

:X86DC
if exist "C:\Program Files\installeddir\app.exe" ( echo ***App is Installed Successfully*** )
if not exist "C:\Program Files\installeddir\app.exe" ( echo ***App is not installed *** )

:X64DC
if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\installeddir\app.exe" ( echo ***App is Installed Successfully*** )    
if not exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\installeddir\app.exe" ( echo ***App is not installed*** )
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something like this be clearer? Also eliminates the issue of making assumptions about the processor_architecture variable pointed out by @MBu above.

```
if defined ProgramFiles(x86^) (
    set appDir=%ProgramFiles(x86^)%\installeddir
) else (
    set appDir=%ProgramFiles%\installeddir
)

if exist %appDir%\app.exe (
    echo We're installed in %appDir%. Woo hoo!
) else (
    echo Nope. Not installed.
)
```

Another alternative that just now occurs to me would be for your installation program or batch file to write a key to the registry with the installation location (can be done with reg.exe, a standard Windows utility). I'd be happy to flesh *that* solution out a bit more if you're interested.

**Note:** "ProgramFiles(x86^)" Closing parentheses must be Escaped or else multiline IF/FOR won't work because will wrongly finish in ")". Better always Escape it, might be within an IF in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When run on x86, your script will execute both code blocks: for x86 and x64. You have to insert `goto :eof` just before `:x64dc` label or add another label (say `:end`) at the end of the script and insert `goto end` just before `:x64dc` label

Another problem is the value of `%processor_architecture%` variable. My machine (Windows 7 x64) returns `AMD64`, not `X64`. So in my case neither of `if` instructions results in a jump, so again both code blocks are executed.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/305901/possible-values-of-processor-architecture) for a list of all possible `%processor_architecture%` values.

Comment: No need for `:end` label, there is already `:eof` built in.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. At the time of writing I wasn't sure if `:EOF` works in all circumstances. I edited my answer and included your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if`, `else if` and `else` constructs:

```
if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="x86" (
    if exist "C:\Program Files\installeddir\app.exe" (
        echo ***App is Installed Successfully***
    ) else (
        echo ***App is not installed ***
    )
) else if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="X64" (
    if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\installeddir\app.exe" (
        echo ***App is Installed Successfully***
    ) else (
        echo ***App is not installed***
    )
)
```