# How can I program a script that can tell the difference between x86 & x64?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, batch-file, 32-bit, vbscript

I have a few programs I am currently working with, such as [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com), that have both the 32 and 64-bit versions. I want to make a script (VB or Batch) at the root of the project folder that can "scan" for the proper program to use in accordance with the local machines processor architecture.

Could this be done either with a simple file name trick using variables such as `WinRAR x86.exe` and `WinRAR x64.exe` or use the internal program architecture if renaming the binaries in a given scenario isn't an option?

I have downloaded programs such as [Cheat Engine](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.cheatengine.org/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj23oXJxOnUAhXr7oMKHRXxA6IQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNFNQeH7A3e-vVPY9yRoUTASm_CgoQ), that have both 32 and 64 bit versions that *also* include a binary that can do this.

Can this be done with *simple* script programing, and if so, how and with what script format should I use?

Comment: "Could this be done either with a simple file name trick" - Possibly but not always.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/305901/possible-values-of-processor-architecture

Comment: Dude you are smart, and apparently, willing to learn. In all honesty I suggest you move on to a better scripting language - Python (easily cross platform) and if you wanna specialize on windows, use powershell (even the parent company's seriously dedicated towards making it mainstream) instead of batch script

Comment: I plan on learning other programming languages such as Python, C, C++, C#, and so on. I just don't have the time for that currently. More recently I've been learning Visual Basic (hence why I suggested the option), it seems to be more advanced than batch, and will likely take me longer to learn.

Comment: Okay, if your project isn't a top secret, tell me about it. I'll try to implement it and give you the code with explanation. Just so that you know how fast easy development in Python is. And C, C++ are not scripting languages.

Comment: @aim100k, 
Well, I just want to make a script template with placeholder values that can be easily swapped out. This will essentially be a "launcher" of sorts that will work alongside various programs I have (or make) that will add to their portability and versatility. I would like to narrow the template to only needing to fill in the paths for the 32 bit and 64 bit targets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use batch script or vb script to store output of `wmic os get osarchitecture` and you get a string value saying 32-bit or 64-bit. Then you can use the typical conditional if-then-else to launch the appropriate binary. Problem solved.

#### Alternative method:

The `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` environment variable stores this information , to understand the possible values it returns, refer this blog post-
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2006/03/27/howto-detect-process-bitness/

---

P.S. don't depend on accessing OS drive (remember, it's not always `C:`) looking for `Program Files (x86)` or other hacks like that, you might run into permission issues and it's not the standard way of doing this.

Comment: +1 for *it's not always C:*

Comment: I'm actually going to put both versions of a given program in one folder with the script at the root next to the folders. I'm doing this for the best results _and_ portability. This way the script only needs to search forwards once.

Comment: Nice approach but then you need to manually rename each file (indicating their versions) and hardcode them in your script. Better to keep 2 folders `64-bit` and  `32-bit` in each program's folder. This approach is semantic, easier to write and more scalable :)

Comment: Thank uou for your information, but I'm still relatively new to programming. I can't find a way to incorporate the `%PROCESSOR_ARCITECTURE%` variable into my script. Usually when I make a batch script that runs another program, I place it as far back as desired, then I place the path to the executable or target wraped in quotation marks starting with `".\"`. Other times I use arguments (if posdible) after declaring the target path. Would you be so kind as to provide an example, assuming the two possible paths are `"%X86PROG%\%X86PROG%.exe"` and `"%X64PROG%\%X64PROG%.exe%"`?

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli - `echo %processor_architecture%%processor_architew6432% | findstr 64 >nul && set "prog=%x64prog%\%x64prog%.exe" || set "prog=%x86prog%\%x86prog%.exe"`

Comment: I used your script @dbenham after converting my test scripts to `EXE` binaries and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli - Converting `.bat` files into `.exe` files is rubbish. It doesn't effectively hide your code, and it is known to break some batch code. I don't know if that is the cause of your failure, but the code I posted works for me in a normal `.bat` script, and it should work in general.

Comment: @dbenham, I used your original script in an un-altered state, including the preset values I provided. I have tried changing several different approaches, but I cannot get the program to work. A `cmd` window appears for a brief moment, but disappears rather quickly. Is there another method using batch scripting?

Comment: @dbenham `%processor_architew6432%`? That is undefined. Did you mean `%ProgramW6432%`? Even so, isn't it better to check the OS bitness using `wmic OS get OSArchitecture`. Windows could be running 32 bit on a 64 bit chip ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yes, WMIC is more reliable, because the env variables can be overwritten. But the OP expressed interest in using the variables. And yes, `%processor_architew6432%` is normally undefined - it is only defined if WOW64 is in play, in which case `%processor_architecture%` gives an incomplete answer. Follow the link in the answer above for more info.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks. Again I learn from the master :)